# Cannot set hidden form field in symfony using jquery

Tags: jquery, symfony1

I have a hidden form field called patient_id which I need to set using jquery.  I set it using the following code along with another 2 fields :

```
$('#investigation_patient_id').val($('#patient_id').html());              
$('#patient_first_name').val($('#patient_fname').html());
$('#patient_last_name').val($('#patient_sname').html());
```

When I do an alert on $('#investigation_patient_id') it alerts the correct value.  Although when I inspect the field in firebug after setting it, there is no value attribute, never mind a value for that.  But when I inspect the other fields set above, they have the right value.

When I submit the form then do a die statement:

```
die($request->getPostParameter("investigation[patient_id]"));
```

the die statement is blank, though if I die on the other form fields I set, they show up.  A print_r of $request also shows the value of patient_id is blank.

So what's going on?  Why can't I set a hidden form field?

Comment: Could you add some generated html of the given fields to you question?

Comment: Are you sure your js code is run, and run at the right moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments, it was my mistake, I had two inputs with the same name and id - I hadn't realised that symfony automatically generates hidden fields, meaning I had then I rendered them too, thus two identical inputs